# How can I map over two arrays and return matches as buttons?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

I have an array of key words and an array of objects.  The key words array matches with a title inside an object from the array of objects data.  I want to map over all of my objects looking for a key word match and return that objects title.  I want to do this for each key word in my key word array.

Right now, I can only get it to work for one key word inside of the key word array.  Basically if I have...

> keyWords = [ "sink", "tub", "brush" ]

And my array of objects contains an obj.title which equals these key words, it will only match one of them and will return one button named "sink".

I can't seem to iterate through all of my key words array, but I am iterating through my array of objects.

> data = array of objects
>
> keyWords = array of key words

The goal is to map over data looking for matches in my key words, if I find a match I want to return a button with the matched objects title.  The problem with this is that it doesn't iterate over the keyWords array.  If I add something like keyWords[0] I can look at that specific item for a match, but I want to iterate over all of the keywords and find all matches.

```
const renderKeyButtons = this.props.data.filter(obj => {
   return this.state.keyWords === obj.title;
     }).map((obj, idx) => {
         return (
            <button key={idx}>{obj.title}</button>
         );
 });
```

My guess is that I need to add something to map over the keywords, like an additional (map, idx) => function but I'm not sure how to do this AND return all of the buttons at once.

Comment: I think your filter function should be `return this.state.keyWords.indexOf(obj.title) > -1;`, since this.state.keyWords is an array and you are searching it for obj.title (right?).

Comment: includes seem to do exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare an array to a string. Use [`Array#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to see if string is in array

```
const renderKeyButtons = this.props.data.filter(obj => {
   return this.state.keyWords.includes(obj.title);
     }).map((obj, idx) => {
         return (
            <button key={idx}>{obj.title}</button>
         );
 });
```

Comment: perfect thanks  - I believe this came first so I will accept this one

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to achieve it without any iteration like this

```
const renderKeyButtons = this.props.data.filter(obj => {
   return this.state.keyWords.includes(obj.title);
     }).map((obj, idx) => {
         return (
            <button key={idx}>{obj.title}</button>
         );
 });
```

Comment: Yep, includes do the job just fine.